# probability, choosing the last ball as some color ball

Tags: probability

I have one

**question**:  there are 6 red and 4 blue balls, and one ball is drawn each time, what is the      probability that the first blue appears on the 3rd drawn.

**My incorrect solution:**
(6C2)x(4C1)x 1/(10C3)

**Corrected Solution:** (6C2)x 1/(10C2) x (4C1) x 1/(8C1)

*why "my inccorct solution" is not correct? Why the question involving the "last drawn should be such and such" always need to split up to two experiment, with the 1st experiment concerning with last-1 trial  and the 2nd experiment concerning with the last trial???*

Comment: In your incorrect solution, you found the probability that among the first $3$ draws, there are $2$ red and $1$ blue. But the blue could have appeared on the first trial, or the second.

Comment: ahhhhhh, ok I c

Comment: Another way to think about it.The probability of getting a red in the first draw is $\dfrac{6}{10}$. Probability of getting a red in the second draw is $\dfrac{5}{9}$ and probability of getting a blue in the third draw is $\dfrac{4}{8}$. Multiplying them gives us the required probability.

Comment: thx rah, I see your point now. @AndréNicolas, can u briefly explain, how come when you seperate them (view it as 2 seperate experiment with the 1st exp drawing 2 balls and the 2nd experiment drawing the last ball), it will automatically take care of this? –

Comment: For the first blu to be third chosen, the **third** must be blue, and the first two must be red. The only way we get what we want is rrb. We can calculate the probability of this in a simpler way: $\frac{6}{10}\cdot\frac{5}{9}\cdot\frac{4}{8}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why "my inccorct solution" is not correct?

Because it computes the probability that there are 2 red balls and 1 blue balls amongst the 3 first draws. This is 3 times the probability that there are 2 red balls and 1 blue balls amongst the 3 first draws *and that the blue ball is the third draw*, which is the probability you are asked for. And if you divide your answer by 3, you find
$$
\frac13\cdot\frac{{6\choose2}{4\choose1}}{{10\choose3}}=\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4}{10\cdot9\cdot8}=\frac{{6\choose2}{4\choose1}}{{10\choose2}{8\choose1}}.
$$

Comment: can u briefly explain, how come when you seperate them (view it as 2 seperate experiment with the 1st exp drawing 2 balls and the 2nd experiment drawing the last ball), it will automatically take care of this?

Comment: ?? What you call the two experiments are not "separate".

Comment: (6C2)x 1/(10C2) x (4C1) x 1/(8C1)